# Setting an object's property overwrites this property in objects of same types

Tags: php

Suppose `Customer` has a `Language`, which is another object. Now, if you do something like:

```
$customer1 = Customer::get_test();
$customer2 = Customer::get_test();
$customer1->language = Language::get_english();
$customer2->language = Language::get_chinese();
```

Both customers' languages are now set to chinese. I understand that if I did something like `$customer2 = $customer1` (at the second line) this is to be expected, but why is this the case even in the above-mentioned scenario? Looks like PHP is setting them to refer to the same object in memory even though I am initialising them on separate lines.

What exactly is this behavior in PHP? Is this confined to PHP or is it to be found in other languages as well?

Comment: Can you what how the Customer method `get_test()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP objects are [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) by default.
But you can [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) an object if needed. E.g.

```
$customer1 = Customer::get_test();
$customer2 = clone Customer::get_test();
$customer1->language = Language::get_english();
$customer2->language = Language::get_chinese();
```

In this case $customer1 and $customer2 would refer to two separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are defining the language as static right? Like this:

```
public static language = 'Japanese';
```

And then you are trying to change like that for each new customer you have. But that is like an attribute of your class and all users would have the same no matter how you change. But if you remove the word 'static' from it, each customer can have a different value for the language.
So remove the word static from the properties and methods and your problem would be solved.